# Using Selenium WebDriver in Python to Open Link in New Tab/Window

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm having an issue in *Selenium* where I want to open a link in a new tab. It doesn't have an href either, so obtaining the url as a string doesn't seem possible.

I have tried to use `ActionChains` from *Selenium*, but I can't get it to work.

```
actions = ActionChains(self.driver) 
actions.key_down(Keys.COMMAND)
actions.move_to_element(element)
actions.click()
actions.key_up(Keys.COMMAND)
actions.perform()
```

This code ends up doing nothing as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please read the help topics on asking questions and how to ask a good question. We need more info to help you including the relevant HTML or a page link. http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: could you share your element HTML code...

Answer (score 0):

if webdriver click is not working, you could use javascript to click on an element which opens a new tab/window.

```
def click_using_javascript():
    browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', element)
```